# In a Jmeter test plan how to include multiple JMX files based on input from command line variables

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to build a JMX file using which I should be able to run n number of JMX files in parallel.

Known ways:
copy all the threads groups manually to a test plan and un-check the run sequentially option in test plan settings.

New implementation: Inside a loop controller if I place a Include controller then n number of JMX files can be run sequentially but I want to run JMX files in parallel.

How to run these without lots of rework.
Blazemeter has https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000591677-Creating-a-Multi-Test-Creating-a-Multi-Test
Is there some custom feature/ small block of code in Jmeter that would help my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remain with BlazeMeter stack you might find [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool easier to use, it is capable of [running existing JMeter .jmx scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) by taking them as command-line arguments

So it's quite sufficient to supply several ["scenario" entries](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/#Taurus-Configuration-Syntax) in the YAML file and the mentioned scripts will be executed in parallel:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: test1.jmx
- scenario:
    script: test2.jmx
#etc
```

These "scenarios" can be provided via [`-o` command-line arguments](https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/#Command-Line-Options-Override) as well